# How to get Previous app details when i am opening the page in mobile browser?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, referrer

I am opening mobile web page from an android and IOS app's,
How to identify whether the page opened from app's or directly browsing in browser? using jquery!

document.referrer is returning an empty value when i am opening from android app, and IOS returning the destination host name, instead of source..

Comment: You can't, apps are not webs

Comment: is there any other way to identify that the page opened from app's?

Comment: I'm afraid not. What you can do is make the app open the web on a webview instead sending it to the native browser, then, if you change the webview's user agent, you can check the user agent with javascript